# Complete columns based on values that precede data as table format in SAS

Tags: sas

How should the code be completed to make this work?

Code:

```scss
data ms;
infile 'C';
input cr ls ms color $;
if input @; *statemet that reads the line with one word and complete the color column*
run;
```

Input:

```
Blars  
10      83287   10.00       
20      1748956 30.00   
30  2222222 73.00       
40          833709  90.00   
Klirs  
10      922222  90.50   
20      1222222 10.00   
30  1111111 93.33       
40      8998877 300.90
```

Expected output:

| cr | ls | ms | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 83287 | 10.00 | Blars |
| 20 | 1748956 | 30.00 | Blars |
| 30 | 2222222 | 50.00 | Blars |
| 40 | 833709 | 73.00 | Blars |
| 10 | 922222 | 90.50 | Klirs |
| 20 | 1222222 | 10.00 | Klirs |
| 30 | 1111111 | 93.33 | Klirs |
| 40 | 8998877 | 300.90 | Klirs |

Attempted to read it

Comment: Does your data look like above, or have extra line spaces? Use 2 spaces after the end of a row to help force a new line.

Comment: @Reeza I just modified the text, but my original .txt it's without blank rows

Comment: I updated your post so the example text matches your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Richard, your code could even be more succinct.

```
* attempt to read first 2 chars as number; 
* ?? suppresses errors; 
input num ?? 2. @;

if missing(num) then
    input @1 color $;
else do;
    input @1 cr ls ms;
    output;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just RETAIN the extra variable.  You need some way to detect which type of line you currently are reading.  When it has the COLOR just update the COLOR variable and do not write out an observation.  When it has the actual data then read all of the fields and write an observation.

```
data ms;
  infile 'C' truncover ;
  length color $10 cr ls ms 8;
  retain color;
  input cr ?? @ ;
  if missing(cr) then do;
    color = _infile_;
    delete;
  end;
  input ls ms ;
run;
```

Make sure to define the COLOR column long enough to store the longest value.  This assumes there are no blank lines, as you mentioned in your comment on the original question.

Comment: This doesnt work. The task I need to do, is the word that is alone on the line is the one that
should complete the following rows in the color column until the next word appears and do the same task again.

Comment: @stat did you try it? Works for me with the data you've posted.

Comment: If my first column instead of words, are numbers. May cause an error? I get 
the column created but empty. There's by chance a way of solving it without retain?

Comment: @stat please update your sample data to more accurately reflect your real data.

Comment: RETAIN is just makes it easier to remember the COLOR value.  If your actual data is different then just adjust the method you use to detect which type of line you are on.

Comment: @Reeza Update made. It has the same format now.

Comment: So just read the first column and if it is missing then assume it has the color instead.  If the file is more com[plex you just need to modify the logic used to defect which type of line you are reading.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different method than other solution.

- Use `INPUT @@` to read the full line and hold it in the automatic variable `_infile_`.
- Check `_infile_` variable to see if it contains any numeric values, if so, process as data.
- Otherwise, process as a colour.

```
data have;
infile cards truncover;


*set length and retain color across rows;
length color $10 cr ls ms 8;
retain color;

*read in string;  
input @@;

*check for any digits in string, if any are found, process as data;
if anydigit(_infile_) then do;
input cr ls ms;
output;
end;
*otherwise read in as color;

else input color $;


cards;
Blars  
10      83287   10.00       
20      1748956 30.00   
30  2222222 73.00       
40          833709  90.00   
Klirs  
10      922222  90.50   
20      1222222 10.00   
30  1111111 93.33       
40      8998877 300.90  
;;;;
run;
```

Comment: The extra @ is not needed, but does no harm since both branches include an INPUT statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can scan a held generic input line and then choose which input statement you want based on the scan.

```
data want;
  length color $20 cr ls ms 8;
  retain color;

  infile 'c' missover;
  input @;

  if missing(input(scan(_infile_,1),??best12.)) then
    input @1 color ;
  else
    input @1 cr ls ms ;

  if not missing(cr);
run;
```